# Clitics vs. Inflectional Affix

Tags: affixes

Zwicky and Pullum (1983: 507) state that "*n*'*t* cannot be attached to words containing simple clitics ['*s*/'*ve*], although the simple clitic '*ve* can do so." As such, they don't think (1) is acceptable:

(1) *I'dn't be doing this unless I had to.

but

(2) I'd've smoked more dope when I was young [my example]

However, to my native ears (1) doesn't sound so unacceptable. How would one go about determining its acceptability objectively? Corpora, perhaps?

Comment: (1) doesn't seem acceptable to me.